# What is the difference between error and fault in Spring-WS SOAP calls?

Tags: soap, spring-ws

I am trying to make a SOAP call through a Spring Boot application. The call is returned with statuscode 400 and a SOAP envelope with no content. When the response is processed by WebServiceTemplate, it is characterized as an error and not a fault, and it seems like the SOAP web service I’m trying to reach doesen’t recognize the request at all. The response looks like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body/>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I have debugged the request, and recreated it in postman / insomnia. When posting from either request tool, it seems to work fine. Even if I send trash values for the HTTP headers or the xml body, I get a response like below, along with code 400:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
      <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
      <faultstring>RequestDataInvalid Request data is invalid.</faultstring>
    </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Even if the request contains illegal values, the webservice I’m trying to reach seems to at least recognize the request.

What is the difference between an error and a fault? A big step in solving the problem would be to know why my invalid request is considered an error and not a fault. Can it be that this might be related to connection / network issues? When looking at the SOAP web service URL, it seems like the service has some kind of relation to Microsoft Dynamics Business Central.

Base url:
https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com

Answer (score 0):

I've never used `WebServiceTemplate` but it's possible to have something to do with the status code of the response. The [SOAP specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508) says that a SOAP fault should be received on a status code of 500:

> In case of a SOAP error while processing the request, the SOAP HTTP server MUST issue an HTTP 500 "Internal Server Error" response and include a SOAP message in the response containing a SOAP Fault element (see section 4.4) indicating the SOAP processing error.

You are getting status code 400.

A quick read of the `WebServiceTemplate` [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/api/org/springframework/ws/client/core/WebServiceTemplate.html#setCheckConnectionForFault-boolean-) says this about its `setCheckConnectionForFault` method:

> Indicates whether the connection should be checked for fault indicators (true), or whether we should rely on the message only (false). The default is true.
>
> When using an HTTP transport, this property defines whether to check the HTTP response status code for fault indicators. Both the SOAP specification and the WS-I Basic Profile define that a Web service must return a "500 Internal Server Error" HTTP status code if the response envelope is a Fault. Setting this property to false allows this template to deal with non-conforming services.

Looks like you are dealing with a [non compliant WS-I Basic Profile](http://www.ws-i.org/Profiles/BasicProfile-1.1.html#HTTP_Server_Error_Status_Codes) web service, but the `WebServiceTemplate` is still trying to deal with faults, even when they are not received with a 500 status code, which seems to indicate that an error that isn't a proper fault as per the SOAP and WS-I specs, is considered just that, an error.